# Freemarker - assign expression within quotes

Tags: freemarker

How to put `${expression}` within double quotes like this?

for example:`<User name="" >`

I tried with following but it doesn't work:

`<User name="${expression}" >` get evaluation error

`<User name="${r"${expression}"}" >` get `<User name="${expression}" >`, not the assigned value

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [?html](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_js_string)

```
  <Table name="${expression?html}" >
```

Or [auto-escaping mechanism](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html)

```
<#ftl output_format="HTML">
```

> This built-in is deprecated by the auto-escaping mechanism introduced in 2.3.24

Or [escape](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_escape.html)

```
<#escape x as x?html>
  <Table name="${expression}" >
</#escape>
```